# Asp.net Core Get MediaType from url?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make a simple asp.net core route that returns a file from another url. Something like this:

```
private static HttpClient Client { get; } = new HttpClient();

async public Task<ActionResult<byte[]>> AssetStorage(string id)
{
    var stream = await Client.GetStreamAsync("https://myurl/assetstorage/" + id);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, /* what here? */)
    {
        FileDownloadName = "filename"
    };
}
```

Later the logic will become more complex, but as a test I was trying this.

Anyway, the `"https://myurl/assetstorage/" + id` might return different kinds of files (probably pdfs or images).

Is there a way to get the media type header from that url? So I can set the same one for my route?

---

I found I can do the following:

```
        var response = await Client.GetAsync("url" + id, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        string contentType = response.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First();

        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = "filename"
            };
        }
```

However, that for some reason doesn't include the "Content-Type" header, even though firefox shows it is there on the same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The header was in `response.Content.Headers` rather than `response.Headers`:

```
var response = await Client.GetAsync("url" + id);
string contentType = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First();
return new FileStreamResult(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), contentType);
```